# Batch variable only saving part of diskpart output

Tags: string, batch-file, format

The output of the below code only takes the first word of each line. I want to see if the disk DYN or not.

```
    @echo off
    diskpart /s test9.txt

    for /f %%i in ('diskpart /s test9.txt') do echo %%i
```

Code Outputs:
Disk

[Dashed Lines]

Disk

How do I get the whole line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"tokens=*"` removes leading spaces,this is not the issue here but for general reasons use better:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('diskpart /s test9.txt') do echo %%i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('diskpart /s test9.txt') do echo %%i
```